# Appropriate SER cable routing under heat duct

Tags: electrical, subpanel

I am routing a 2-2-2-4 SER AL Cable from my main panel to a subpanel in an attached garage, through the overhead joists in my unfinished basement.  Should I route the cable as shown in route A, which routes the cable through holes drilled in the joists, but drops and is fastened to the bottom of the joists where the duct is, or route B, which routes the cable through holes drilled in all the joists, and simply loops the cable underneath the duct?  Or neither?
[image]

Comment: This is fairly opinion based, but I'd drill thru the joist about 2/3 - 3/4 up from the bottom and go **over** the duct. The heat from the duct won't materially affect the cable.   Then, if you ever decide to finish the basement, you don't have to install nail plates when you sheetrock the ceiling.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson Interesting, I guess I didn't consider it since the cable would lie on top of the duct that gets hot.  I'll check to see if I have enough room above the duct.

Comment: If you were really worried about it, you could tape a small piece of insulation on the duct where the cable crosses over it. It's probably not needed...in southern states attic temps can get up to 180 F or more and the wiring installed in attics does fine.  There are some de-rating rules that I don't completely understand, but I do get that when a wire gets hot, it's capacity decreases.  In your case most furnaces deliver hot forced air at 120F or less, some are up to 140F but rare.  If the air coming out of your registers is super hot, I'd add that small piece of insulation just to be safe.